# Python: Pandas dt.month giving different results from Excel's month calculation

Tags: python, pandas, analytics

**[SOLVED by Changing the date format for pandas to parse]**

I am trying to calculate Month Name and I checked there is a massive difference when I am using dt.month_name and Excel's month to get the month of transaction.

Context:
I am running an analysis on my own bank transaction. For the simplicity, I have two dates - Value date and Transaction date. I have converted both to datetime format and used dt.month to get the month names. After facing some problems and doing a RCA, I came to the conclusion that the value_counts of months calculated in excel is vastly different from the ones calculated in Python.

[image]

This is after using Transaction date to calculate the month value (py_Month)

[image]

This is after using Value Date to calculate the month (py_month)

The Entire code is as follows:

```
data = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx",sheet_name="Sheet1")
data = data.drop(["S No."],axis=1)
    
# Convert to datetime.
date_cols = ["Value Date","Transaction Date"]
data[date_cols] = data[date_cols].apply(pd.to_datetime)   

val_date  = "Value Date"
tnx_date = "Transaction Date"

data["py_Month"] = data[val_date].dt.month_name()
# data["py_Month"] = data[tnx_date].dt.month_name()
   

vc_df = data[['xl_month', 'py_Month']].apply(pd.Series.value_counts)
vc_df
```

Comment: please provide a [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) dataset as input, it's otherwise impossible to reproduce your issue

Comment: Please, provide a [reproducible pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: I do have that ready and on drive. But Google sheets is acting differently from my Excel on desktop. Added the link in the post, though

Comment: you have date string constants in your xl_month column, you should fix them first

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

The problem was with the parsing of the date formats in Excel and Python.

Explicitly mentioning the format resolved the problem:

```
data[date_cols] = data[date_cols].apply(pd.to_datetime, format='%d/%m/%Y')
```